# convert js code to be used with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have the following slider code which uses Mootools:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    // Declaring increment vars
    var totIncrement = 0;
    var increment = 230;
    var maxRightIncrement = increment * (-3);

    // FX var
    var fx = new Fx.Style('myList', 'margin-left', {
        duration: 500,
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Back.easeInOut,
        wait: true
    });
});
```

I wanted to use jQuery javascript. Can anybody tell me how to convert the above code to jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What parts are you having difficulty with? (PS it's generall Good Form to have a go yourself, and show us before asking us to help you do it).

Comment: Thanx Taryn, I am having problem with Fx.Style equivalent of it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Declaring increment vars     
    var totIncrement = 0;     
    var increment = 230;     
    var maxRightIncrement = increment*(-3); 

    $('#myList').animate({ 'margin-left' : increment }, 500, 'easeInOut');
});
```

Comment: I think you want `easeInOutBack` rather than `easeInOut` here, per the OP's original example. See also: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html